# Nested loop through 2 large sets of data

Tags: c#, loops, nested

I have 2 sets of data from different systems.  About 20,000 records a piece.  One set of data is a `List<Objects>`, the other is a RecordSet from a system I have no control over (I can only ask for records and receive the recordset).

I need to merge data between the 2, matching on a key that exists in both lists, by putting some data from the Recordset into the matching object structure.  The nested loop I've tried is entirely too slow.

Is there a fast way to get the match and move on to the next object?

EDIT:  EXISTING CODE

This is a very basic nested loop

```
results = _sr.SearchLst(ut.ToString(), searchSettings);

foreach (BL.Packet ePacket in eList) {

    for (Int32 j = 0; j < results.Rows.Length; j++) {

        String acckey = results.Rows[0].Data.GetValue(1).ToString();
        String taskname = results.Rows[0].Data.GetValue(2).ToString();

        if (acckey == ePacket.RecKey.ToString()) {
            ePacket.prop1 = taskname;
            ePacket.prop2 = acckey;
        }
    }
}
```

I did also look at Linq, but couldn't get a grasp of how the two would go together...I'm not sure Linq would be faster anyway.

SOLUTION:

Here's basically what I ended up doing.

```
//move object from list to dictionary
var dict = eList.Cast<BaseObj>().ToDictionary(o => o.RecKey, o => o);

results = _sr.SearchLst(ut.ToString(), searchSettings);
if (results.Rows.Length > 0) {

    //loop through all rows in recordset
    for (Int32 j = 0; j < results.Rows.Length; j++) {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(results.Rows[j].Data.GetValue(1)); 
        taskname = results.Rows[j].Data.GetValue(2).ToString();

        if (dict.ContainsKey(id)) {
            //recordset id found in dictionary, so grab taskname
            ePacket = ((BL.Packet)dict[id]);
            ePacket.prop1 = taskname;
        }
    }
}

//move dictionary back to list
List<BaseObj> eListReturn = new List<BaseObj>(dict.Values);
return eListReturn;
```

Thanks to everyone for the assistance!

Comment: Have you tried joining them using LINQ?

Comment: Please post your existing code.

Comment: What is underlying type of a key you've mentioned - `matching on a key that exists in...`?

Comment: I've added sample code.  The keys I'm matching are string and int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary<TypeOfKey, SomeObject>` on the list collection you have in memory, populate the dictionary using the key as key and the object as value.

Loop over the record set. Using the dictionary you can do an O(1) lookup of the matching element, so you can eliminate the looping over the in-memory collection.

Comment: Is the converting a List to a Dictionary (or adding the List to a Dictionary) process fast?

Comment: Can you expand on your idea?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var Object = from o in Objects
             join r in RecordSet equal o.YourKey equal r.YourForeignKey
             select Object { x = r.YourProperty };
```

For additional reference on LINQ here are 101 samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

(Old message for reference)

Use LINQ to join the two pieces if info into a single IEnumerable (like a List).
Something like

```
var combinedData = from i in listItems
                   join r in recordSet on r.ID equals i.ID
                   select new { i.Name, r.Property };
```

Here's a link to a join using LINQ http://www.dotnetperls.com/join
Also, google LINQ examples for your .net platform, there are lots out there and it's quite fast at doing exactly what you are looking for.

After looking around SO for similar threads I found some stuff that is quite helpful which I will summarize here. The problem is, we aren't sure what you want to do in the inner brackets of the loop.

I'm assuming you only want a set of "widgets" that can be joined with a list of "gadgets" by a key.

If you want a bunch of widgets and gadgets joined into a new whatsits object - maybe you're building a flat table for a chart or something use this example:

```
var whatsits = from w in widgets
               join g in gadgets on w.gadgetID equal g.ID
               select new whatsit { name = w.name, id = w.ID };
```

If you want to get a bunch of widgets joined with gadgets, where a gadget property = some value, and then do work on each gadget, you first collect the gadgets and then foreach over the new collection like so:

```
var widgetList = from w in widgets
                 join g in gadgets on w.gadgetID equals g.ID
                 where g.Name = "whatsit"
                 select w;

foreach (widget w in widgetList)
{
    // Do a bunch of stuff to each widget
}
```

Note, it might be worth doing a performance test on the LINQ above to see if it runs better widget first, or gadget first in the join.

Comment: I've updated the sample to include some code in the inner brackets.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, based on the code in your brackets, all you are doing is aggregating two different classes into a new flat class, so to speak. I would use LINQ sample #2, which would remove the need for a foreach loop alltogether.

Comment: What I have to return from the method is actually the List<Object> that I'm passing in (widgets in this case) with all of the data intact and the x property in each object loaded with the value from the matching recordset row.  Does that make sense?  I've tried the suggestion below with the dictionary and one foreach, which is working, but no foreach's would be better if it can be done this way.  I have no experience with Linq at all and when I try to put my object and recordset (from the sample) into your example, I get syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an abstraction layer over the RecordSet objects and their API which allow accessing using a key. It would be sort of like a dictionary from key to RecordSet.

You will have two iterations - one over each collection. Two iterations is O(N), whereas a nested loop is O(N^2).

Answer (score 0):

If the recordset returns values in sorted order e.g.

value    key

'val'  |  1

'val2' |  2

'val2' |  3

'val2' |  4

Then you might do a sort-merge join. here is a pseudo code

```
while (!endofRecordset || !endofMyCollection) do
   if (recorset[rIndex].Key==myList[lIndex].Key)
       Join(recorset[rIndex], myList[lIndex])
   else if (recordset[rIndex] > myList[lIndex])
       lIndex++
   else 
       rIndex++
end while
```

**EDIT:**

here is more info about [sort-merge join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join) with example in c#